# Return values of Bash/Dialog --checklist

Tags: linux, bash, user-interface, dialog

I got lost with getting return values for a bash dialog. The problem is: how to get return values of a --checklist ? It's a multiple choice list, where I need a return value of every item. Here is the code:

```
dialog --checklist "package timing" 20 75 5 \
                   "Package A" "3 s, 4 MB" on \
                   "Package B" "4 s, 2 MB" on \
                   "Package C" "1 s, 5 MB" on \
                   "Package D" "4 s, 2 MB" on \
                   "Package E" "Very Fast" off
                   retval=$?
                   CHOICE_PACKAGES=$RETVAL
```

First I thought, an array will be the return value. Apparently it isn't so.
Does anybody know how to get all the return values of every item ?

[Post-Edit:] Maybe in this case, if someone has a good link about a *complete* Bash-Tutorial, I would appreciate that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.txt

says that

> On  exit,  a  list  of the tag strings of those entries that are
>                 turned on will be printed on dialog's output.

So you can save the output to a temporary file

```
dialog <....> 2> tempfile
```

and then parse the contents of `tempfile`.  Your example will contain something like

`"Package A" "Package B" "Package D"`

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand, how do I get these values now into variables ?

Comment: See my expanded answer.